# Changing Drush path

Tags: drush

I previously had Drush working on my VPS, but for some reason since a server update Drush can no longer be located.

If I do **'which drush'** the output is **'/root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush'**
which matches what is in my .bash_profile:

```
PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

My drush installation is actually at **/opt/drush-8.x/vendor/drush/drush**

This may seem like an obvious answer, but when I tried editing .bash_profile to what made sense to me, something got broken (couldn't use any commands) and my hosts had to restore my old .bash_profile for me. I may just have made a typo then, but wanted someone to confirm **exactly** what my .bash_profile should say before I try again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a Bash / shell question - how to modify the path or set an alias. Anyway, replace

```
PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

with

```
PATH="/opt/drush-8.x/vendor/drush/drush:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

assuming you may have other stuff in `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` that you stil want to use.

If you want to be 110% sure that you don't break something, try it in Bash before modifying .bash_profile - just copy and paste the line inside Bash.

Comment: Thank you - that's worked for the path, I'm now getting other errors - but's a separate question!